# BigQuery - data transfer success but destination table stays empty

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

**Final goal**: transfer csv file contents from google cloud storage bucket to a table in BigQuery dataset.

**problem**: data transfer seems to be working, not showing any errors/warnings but the data fails to reach the destination table.

- dataset/table created beforehand
- bkt created and one csv file uploaded
- data transfer created and configured to transfer all files from the above bucket to my destination table.
- transfer is defined On-Demand.

i'm new to bigQuery and GCP but the idea of data transfer seems pretty intuitive to me.
i assume i'm missing something here but the flow does not notify me.
so i thought it might be permissions (i have bigQuery Admin role among other so..)
i thought its a location/region thing but all resources are in EU..

can you help me understand what else am i missing ?
attaching some pics that might help.

[Bucket Configuration (where my csv resides)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7OAO.png)

[Destination Table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CASfz.png)

[Transfer Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7JFL.png)

[Data Transfer output showing a successful action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3ZPf.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check whether you have minimum 'BigQuery Data Editor' role on your id ? It could be a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer Vibhor. after i updated my roles with BQ Data Editor i managed to make this work. i still dont understand why didnt i get any notification, it seems like a problem/bug to me. anyhow, can you please post this as an answer so i can accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please have minimum '**BigQuery Data Editor**' role on your id to solve your problem.

Comment: What do you mean "minimum 'BigQuery Data Editor' role"??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what's wrong since no error is returned but two points I usually check in that cases:

- did you try reloading the BigQuery workspace ? It doesn't automatically refresh so you have to reload to see the changes (if any..)
- have you tried loading the csv directly from the workspace (create Table from Cloud storage in the UI), without setting the Data transfer ? This way you can check straight away if you have an issue with your file

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . i did try reloading which did not work. i would have tried your suggestion about loading directly but the comment above about "BigQuery Data Editor" role solved it.